# Timing confusion in AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a code to plot a real time graph using a javascript library "FLOT". I am getting the data from mysql every 500mS using AJAX technology.
I have the main() function that is calling handleresponse() function which retreives data from database and in the  handleresponse() function again I have given setTimeout(main(),500). So, every 500mS the things are getting repeated and dynamically the graph is getting plotted. But the time axis is not moving according to the data.. the data is getting updated only at a particular point. the appearance of the data and time axis is not synchronised.

Comment: Impossible to say what's wrong with your code without seeing it.

Comment: It might help if you showed some code. Apart from that: Are you aware that ajax calls are asynchronous? That means your response to the call might actualy take substantially longer than 500 ms.

Comment: Welcome on this site uddipana. I'm afraid your question doesn't really meet the standards of this site. To get an accurate answer, you should show us a piece of code that highlights your issue. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a pleasure to debug your problem if there would be some code.

Anyway here is a suggestion:

You create a timeout to update the graph. And you have a timer for the AJAX call?

Try to combine these (you only need one timer). Just use the timer for the AJAX call and update the graph if the request is successfull/ready. So the graph update should be synchronized with your gathered Data.

Comment: Thank You Livingstone, Your suggestion really worked

Comment: Happy to hear that thats helped you. 

Please dont forget to mark the answer so other users may find it easier.